# `Pluck` but for a single retrieved record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a record object:

```rb
2.7.0 :005 > o = OauthUser.first
  OauthUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "oauth_users".* FROM "oauth_users" ORDER BY "oauth_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2.7.0 :006 > o
 => #<OauthUser id: 1, name: "Person Name", email: "person@email.com", oauth_id: "111111111111111", oauth_provider: "google", oauth_token: "blahblahblah...", oauth_refresh_token: nil, oauth_expires_at: "2020-11-13 18:22:24", sync_emails: nil, last_email_sync: nil, manual_query: nil, created_at: "2020-11-13 17:22:25", updated_at: "2020-11-13 17:22:25">
```

In a quick, dirty fashion I'm just throwing this into a view with a `.to_json` call so I can see the various attributes on screen.
But I want to remove a few attributes that I don't care to actually display or shouldn't display for security reasons.

I thought I could just write a method like this:

```rb
# app/models/oauth_user.rb
def details
  # don't show sensitive tokens, only show fields I care to see
  pluck(:id, :oauth_id, :oauth_expires_at, :sync_emails, :last_email_sync, :manual_query)
end
```

But `pluck` is for queries.

I know I could manually do something in the view or build a hash in the model, but I'm thinking there's already a method for what I'm after, just not finding it on Google.

I have a single record already, don't need to query with `pluck` or `select`; or `map` results.

Is there a simple way to whitelist or blacklist attributes I want displayed for a single record?

I've tried `pluck`, `select`, `map` and `tap` to no avail.

Comment: what about `.to_json(only: %w[id oauth_id])` ? Or `.to_json(except: [...])`

Comment: Wowza. I didn't think to mutate the JSON, nor did I know you could do `only` and `except` on them. Thanks! If you wanna post this as an answer, I'll accept it and give you those sweet, sweet points.

Comment: You could also use `attributes.values_at(:id, :oauth_id, :etc)` to get an array like `pluck` gives

Comment: Genius! @maxpleaner, thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like there are a decent number of options but generally speaking what you are talking about is a presenter pattern.

If you wanted a `Hash` from your model that would be simple:

```
def details
  attributes.slice('id', 'oauth_id', 'oauth_expires_at', 
                   'sync_emails', 'last_email_sync', 'manual_query') 
end
```

If you wanted a more formal object then this is where the presenter comes in (there are many libraries for this but we will just write our own for the sake of this question)

```
class OauthUserPresenter
  WHITELIST = %w(id oauth_id oauth_expires_at sync_emails last_email_sync manual_query)
  WHITELIST.each {|attr| define_method(attr) {@_exposed_attributes[attr]}}

  def initialize(user) 
     @_exposed_attributes = user.attributes.slice(WHITELIST)
  end 

  def to_hash #this will allow for #as_json and #to_json 
    @_exposed_attributes
  end

end
```

Then you can call as

```
o = OauthUserPresenter.new(OauthUser.first)
```

now `o` is technically a read only presenter object. None of the other attributes will be exposed and you can still access the methods as `id`, `oauth_id`, etc.

Presenters also allow you to add other methods without cluttering the model e.g.

```
class OauthUserPresenter
   def expired? 
     begin
       Time.parse(oauth_expires_at) <= Time.now
     rescue TypeError, ArgumentError #handle nil, empty string, and invalid times
       true
     end
   end 
end
```

Comment: In this case, the hash is totally fine, but I really appreciate the Presenter overview. Something I've started hearing about but hadn't really checked out yet. Thanks!